# Designing an API for the client to a 3rd-party service

Tags: api, scala

I am fairly new to Scala and I'm working on an application (library) which is a client to a 3rd-party service (I'm not able to modify the server side and it uses custom binary protocol). I use Netty for networking.

I want to design an API which should allow users to:

- Send requests to the server
- Send requests to the server and get the response asynchronously
- Subscribe to events triggered by the server (having multiple asynchronous event handlers which should be able to send requests as well)

I am not sure how should I design it. Exploring Scala, I stumble upon a bunch of information about Actor model, but I am not sure if it can be applied there and if it can, how.

I'd like to get some recommendations on the way I should take.

Comment: I have no idea what you question is or what you want to do other than "build an API with events." Can you add some clarification?

Comment: @wheaties Well, I want to "build an API with events" and, as I said in [one of the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784318/designing-an-api-for-the-client-to-a-3rd-party-service#comment31410989_20908612), with "interactive" objects representing entities from the service. I am asking for design patterns which may help me to make the API user-friendly, "scala-friendly", and flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Observables

This looks like a good example for the Obesrvable pattern. This pattern comes from the [Reactive Extensions of .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx), but is also available for [Java](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava) and [Scala](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/tree/master/language-adaptors/rxjava-scala). The library is provided by Netflix and has a really good quality.

This pattern has a good theoretical foundation --- it is the dual to the iterator in the category theoretical sense. But more important, it has a lot of practical ideas in it. Especially it handles time very good, e.g. you can limit the event rate you want to get.

With an observable you can process events on avery high level. In .NET it looks a lot like an SQL query. You can register for certain events ("FROM"), filter them ("WHERE") and finally process them ("SELECT"). In Scala you can use standard monadic API (map, filter, flatMap) and of course "for expressions".

An example can look like

```
stackoverflowQuestions.filter(_.tag == "Scala").map(_.subject).throttleLast(1 second).subscribe(println _)
```

Obeservables take away a lot of problems you will have with event based systems

- Handling subsrcriptions
- Handling errors
- Filtering and pre-processing events
- Buffering events

### Structuring the API

Your API should provide an obesrvable for each event source you have. For procedure calls you provide a function that will map the function call to an obesrvable. This function will call the remote procedure and provide the result through the obeservable.

### Implementation details

Add the following dependency to your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies +=     "com.netflix.rxjava" % "rxjava-scala" % "0.15.0"
```

You can then use the following pattern to convert a callback to an obeservable (given your remote API has some way to register and unregister a callback):

```
private val callbackFunc : (rx.lang.scala.Observer[String]) => rx.lang.scala.Subscription = { o =>
  val listener = {
    case Value(s) => o.onNext(s)
    case Error(e) => o.onError(o)
  }

  remote.subscribe(listener)

  // Return an interface to cancel the subscription
  new Subscription {
    val unsubscribed = new AtomicBoolean(false)
    def isUnsubscribed: Boolean = unsubscribed.get()

    val asJavaSubscription: rx.Subscription = new rx.Subscription {
      def unsubscribe() {
        remote.unsubscribe(listener)
        unsubscribed.set(true)
      }
    }
  }
```

If you have some specific questions, just ask and I can refine the answer

### Additional ressources

There is a very nice [course](https://www.coursera.org/course/reactive) from Martin Odersky et al. at coursera, covering Observables and other reactive techniques.

Comment: I've read a few articles and observables seem like a very good way to work with events. Are there any advantages of returning results of procedure calls using observables instead of regular Scala futures if there will never be more than 1 result object?

Comment: The main advantage would be when the rest of the API also consists of obeservables. Then you can easily combine multiple (observable) event streams (e.g. with ++, zip or flatMap) and then work with the resulting stream.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the Scala-ish way to expose asynchronous functionality to user code is to return a `scala.concurrent.Future[T]`.

If you're going the actor route, you might consider encapsulating the binary communication within the context of a single actor class.  You can scale the instances of this proxy actor using [Akka's router support](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/routing.html), and you could produce response futures easily using the *ask pattern*.  There are a few nice libraries (*Spray*, *Play Framework*) that make wrapping e.g. a RESTful or even WebSocket layer over Akka almost trivial.

A nice model for the pub-sub functionality might be to define a `Publisher` trait that you can mix in to some actor subclasses.  This could define some state to keep track of subscribers, handle `Subscribe` and `Unsubscribe` messages, and provide some sort of convenient method for broadcasting messages:

```
  /**
    * Sends a copy of the supplied event object to every subscriber of
    * the event object class and superclasses.
    */
  protected[this] def publish[T](event: T) {
    for (subscriber <- subscribersFor(event)) subscriber ! event
  }
```

These are just some ideas based on doing something similar in some recent projects.  Feel free to elaborate on your use case if you need more specific direction.  Also, the [Akka user list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/akka-user) is a great resource for general questions like this, if indeed you're interested in exploring actors in Scala.

Comment: I also would like to have objects which represent "service entities". I could just use case classes, but there're two things I'd like: 1) Some of the entities can get real-time updates from the service, and I want to have them available to the API user as soon as possible; 2) I would like the objects to have methods for interacting/modifying them. Can I make it go nicely with the actor model or am I thinking in a completely wrong direction?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [spray-client library](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.0/spray-client/).  This provides HTTP request functionality (I'm assuming the server you want to talk to is a web service?).  It gives you a pretty nice DSL for building requests and is all about being asynchronous.  It does use the akka Actor model behind the scenes, but you do not have to build your own Actors to use it.  Instead the you can just use scala's Future model for handling things asynchronously.  A good introduction to the Future model is [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).

The basic building block of spray-client is a "pipeline" which maps an HttpRequest to a Future containing an HttpResponse:

```
// this is from the spray-client docs
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive

val response: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(Get("http://spray.io/"))
```

You can take this basic building block and build it up into a client API in a couple of steps.  First, make a class that sets up a pipeline and defines some intermediate helpers demonstrating [ResponseTransformation](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.0/spray-httpx/response-transformation/#responsetransformation) techniques:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import spray.can.client.HttpClient
import spray.client.HttpConduit
import spray.client.HttpConduit._
import spray.http.{HttpRequest, HttpResponse, FormData}
import spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller
import spray.io.IOExtension

type Pipeline = (HttpRequest) => Future[HttpResponse]

// this is basically spray-client boilerplate     
def createPipeline(system: ActorSystem, host: String, port: Int): Pipeline = {
    val httpClient = system.actorOf(Props(new HttpClient(IOExtension(system).ioBridge())))
    val conduit = system.actorOf(props = Props(new HttpConduit(httpClient, host, port)))

    sendReceive(conduit)
}

private var pipeline: Pipeline = _
// unmarshalls to a specific type, e.g. a case class representing a datamodel
private def unmarshallingPipeline[T](implicit ec:ExecutionContext, um:Unmarshaller[T]) = (pipeline ~> unmarshal[T])
// for requests that don't return any content.  If you get a successful Future it worked; if there's an error you'll get a failed future from the errorFilter below.
private def unitPipeline(implicit ec:ExecutionContext) = (pipeline ~>  { _:HttpResponse => () })
// similar to unitPipeline, but where you care about the specific response code.
private def statusPipeline(implicit ec:ExecutionContext) = (pipeline -> {r:HttpResponse => r.status})

// if you want standard error handling create a filter like this
// RemoteServerError and RemoteClientError are custom exception classes
// not shown here.
val errorFilter = { response:HttpResponse =>
  if(response.status.isSuccess) response
  else if(response.status.value >= 500) throw RemoteServerError(response)
  else throw RemoteClientError(response)
}

pipeline = (createPipeline(system, "yourHost", 8080) ~> errorFilter)
```

Then you can use wrap these up in methods tied to specific requests/responses that becomes the public API.  For example, suppose the service has a "ping" GET endpoint that returns a string ("pong") and a "form" POST endpoint where you post form data and receive a DataModel in return:

```
def ping()(implicit ec:ExecutionContext, um:Unmarshaller[String]): Future[String] =
    unmarshallingPipeline(Get("/ping"))

def form(formData: Map[String, String])(implicit ec:ExecutionContext, um:Unmarshaller[DataModel]): Future[DataModel] = 
    unmarshallingPipeline(Post("/form"), FormData(formData))
```

And then someone could use the API like this:

```
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

API.ping() foreach(println)  // will print out "pong" when response comes back

API.form(Map("a" -> "b") onComplete {
    case Success(dataModel) => println("Form accepted. Server returned DataModel: " + dataModel)
    case Failure(e) => println("Oh noes, the form didn't go through! " + e)
}
```

I'm not sure if you will find direct support in spray-client for your third bullet point about subscribing to events. Are these events being generated by the server and somehow sent to your client outside the scope of a specific HTTP request? If so, then spray-client will probably not be able to help directly (though your event handlers could still use it to send  requests).  Are the events occurring on the client side, e.g. the completion of deferred processing initially triggered by a response from the server?  If so, you could actually probably get pretty far just by using the functionality in Future, but depending on your use cases, using Actors might make sense.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer, however, as I said in the question,  server side uses custom binary protocol.

Comment: Ooops, I missed that.  Well, you'll obviously have to roll your own stuff to handle the protocol.  You might build on top of the networking implementation in Akka, look [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0-RC1/scala/io-codec.html).  I haven't delved into it myself and can't offer more detailed advice, sorry.